# Editing php.ini is not causing any effect

Tags: php, oauth, mamp

I tried everything, but I can't make it work. I recently installed MAMP. The `PRO` version came with an option to add `OAuth` via a checkbox, but now that the PRO version expired I need to install it by hand. 
When I check `phpinfo()` on my browser it says that the path to my `php.ini` file is:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/conf/php.ini
```

Also, there is `(none)` under `additional ini files`. So I am pretty sure that is the correct `php.ini` file

The problem is that after adding the OAuth extension to the ini file, and restarting MAMP, `PHP` still can't find OAuth.

Also strange is that I don't see any of the other enabled extensions (like mcrypt) in the `phpinfo()` output.

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Ugh.. Damn you MAMP! Had that issue a lot of times. Might be because of several reasons tho... Are you sure you are installing the extension in the right extension_dir?

Comment: Check your http servers error log file when you restart it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got something, `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/oauth.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/oauth.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0` is this a wrong PATH? I installed OAuth by `sudo pecl install oauth`

Answer (score 0):

After much debugging, this is what I did in order to figure out the problem and solve it.

As suggested in the comments of my question, once I checked the `http` logs I found out that `PHP` was not finding the extensions.

I checked php.ini for `extension_dir` and it was pointing to a different path than the one that pecl was installing packages on.

If you need to find that path, simply use:

```
pear config-get php_dir
```

After correcting that everything works fine.